# Не понимаю как создать двумерный массив в Python, у меня получается одномерный

Tags: python, python-3.x

Принялся делать задачу по транспонированию. На бумаге все выглядит очень хорошо. Мы заменяем элементы матрицы с индексами `a[i][j]` на `a[j][i]` и задача решена. Но при реализации возникла проблема. Не понимаю как создать двумерный массив (матрицу), у меня получается одномерный. Вот код.

```
array1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
array2=[]

for i in range(len(array1)):
    for j in range(len(array1[i])):
        array2.append(array1[j][i])
        #print(array2)

print(array2)
```

Comment: вы хотели сказать, что вместо вложенного (2D) списка (представляющего матрицу), у вас плоский (одномерный) список получается.

Comment: связанный (с заголовком) вопрос [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279)

Comment: Да, именно так. Одномерный список можно же считать вектор- строкой или вектором.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в коде. Вот правильный вариант:

```
array1=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
array2=[]
for i in range(0, len(array1[0])):
    array2.append([])
    for j in range(0, len(array1)):
        array2[i].append(array1[j][i])
print(array2)
```

Так как размерности всех векторов в матрице равны, то не имеет разницы, размерность какого вектора(длину списка) брать за образец
Смысл кода объяснять надо?

Comment: интерпретатор говорит, что выходит за пределы списка.

Comment: Прошу прощения, в коде опечатка, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Даниил Середа@ снова ругается интерпретатор. Можете ли пояснить код, если не затруднит?

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Ох    
Простите    
Невнимательность- смертный грех для программиста    
Я две скобки забыл    
Все исправил уже

Comment: Спасибо! я сам уже протупил, не заметил отсутствие 2х коробок

Answer (score 4):

С использованием модуля Numpy:

```
import numpy as np    # pip install numpy

In [121]: np.array(array1).T
Out[121]:
array([[ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11],
       [ 3,  6,  9, 12]])
```

в виде списка списков:

```
In [122]: np.array(array1).T.tolist()
Out[122]: [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

Comment: О, спасибо. Как раз хотел разобрать транспонирование с Numpy/

Comment: @AlexSapsay, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
b = [[x[i] for x in a] for i in range(len(a[0]))]
print (b)
```

Comment: Еще я с генераторами не разобрался. Решение красивое. Даже не было идей их применить к задаче. Теперь буду знать как.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, вероятно, вовсе не по транспонированию, а по языку.

Классических массивов в Python нет. Однако в стандартную библиотеку входит модуль [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html). А для более-менее серьезных вычислений есть [numpy](http://www.numpy.org)

Comment: Да, я хотел поработать с массивами без стандартных библиотек. Что бы ручками покрутить и примерно представлять, что происходит в Numpy